# PHP @ foreach warning

Tags: php

I have a PHP foreach from an array, the array is given to me by my DB provider via a soap web service so I cannot change the array I get. When there are no elements to return, I get an empty array, this results in

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

the loop looks like

```
foreach (($point1['return']) as $val)
```

Where can I put an @ to stop this warning, and if I cant, what I do I do to turn off php warnings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hiding the warning is not the right way. You should check whether it exists and is an array.

```
if (is_array($point1['return'])) {
    foreach ($point1['return'] as $val)  {
         ...
    }
}
```

[PHP is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

Actually, turning off warnings or using the @ operator is not the right way to go 99% of the time.

**Solve the problem instead of hiding it.**

Answer (score 7):

foreach() can handle not only [arrays](http://docs.php.net/language.types.array) but [also objects](http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.iterations) by either using the the default "all visible properties" implementation or a custom implementation via the [traversable](http://docs.php.net/class.traversable)/[iterator](http://docs.php.net/class.iterator) interface.
And a "DB provider via a soap web service" is something where I'd keep an eye on the possibility of (suddenly) having an object/iterator instead of a plain array.
So, if you're going to test the existence and data type before passing the variable to foreach, you *should consider* not only testing for [`is_array()`](http://docs.php.net/is_array) but also for [`instanceof Traversable`](http://docs.php.net/instanceof).

```
<?php
class Foo implements Iterator {
    protected $v = 0;
    public function current() { return $this->v; }
    public function key() { return $this->v; }
    public function next() { ++$this->v; }
    public function rewind() { $this->v=0; }
    public function valid() { return 10>$this->v; }
}

//$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$a = new Foo;


if( is_array($a) || $a instanceof Traversable ) {
    foreach($a as $e) {
        echo $e, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

An empty array does not cause that error, the problem is that you are trying to iterate trough something that **is not** an array. You could add a check using [is_array](http://php.net/is_array) function.

Answer (score 4):

Better to let errors display but check that the input is an array first. So you could wrap the foreach in an if, like this:

```
if ((is_array($point1)) && (is_array($point1['return']))) {
    foreach (($point1['return']) as $val) 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check first for an array:

```
if(is_array($point1['return']))
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also explicitly cast the argument to array:

```
foreach ((array) $point1['return'] as $val)  {
```

Note: this still will issue undefined index, if there is no 'return' key in `$point1`

Answer (score 1):

Check whether that is actually an array. with [`is_array();`](http://php.net/is_array) !! 
There's no need to suppress the warning. 
As a matter of fact, It's not possible to suppress that invalid argument warning.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into your function file:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr){
     if(stristr($errstr,'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()')){
        return true;
    }
        return false;
});
```